# Filter query by one parameter or two

Tags: sql, t-sql, reporting-services

I'm trying to create a report where the user can select either parameter option and it will filter by chosen parameter, or filter by both.

Currently I'm using an OR statement like so:

```
   SELECT a,b
   FROM table a
   WHERE (a = @A) OR (b=@b)
```

The issue is when I try and enter a value for both it only filters by one.  How do I change it so it will filter each one out but at the same time keep the ability to filter by only one?

Comment: WHERE (a = @A or A IS NULL) AND (b=@b OR b IS NULL)

Comment: @user2460637 You should add that as an answer (but changing it to `WHERE (a = @A or @A IS NULL) AND (b=@b OR @b IS NULL)`

Comment: upps sorry u are right

Comment: No rows are returning when I enter only one value for one parameter.

Comment: @Sewder And are there rows for that value of your parameter?.

Comment: Yes, right now if I enter value for BOTH parameters it will return row.  But I leave one blank, it will not return rows or I get an error message of Count Field Incorrect.

Comment: Look, from the database perspective, the answer is correct. Now, you are using SSRS, but haven't provided the details required (the Count Field Incorrect error isn't database related). You need to explain **how** did you define your parameters, since that's where your problem is (is it multivalue?, accept nulls?, accept blanks?, is populated from a dataset?, does it have a default value?, etc)

Comment: Each parameter is text type and allows blank value. Not multivalue and doesn't accept Nulls.

It is populated from a dataset and there are not default values.

Comment: If the parameters don't accept `NULL`s, what makes you think that the `OR @A IS NULL` part will work?. It seems like you are passing a blank value instead, something like `OR @a = ''`

Comment: You make a good point, sorry for not clarifying but I've been tweaking this report like crazy now.  I had it to accept nulls, but it gave me a different error message that said "Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt".  Any ideas?

Comment: @Sewder Not really, I don't seem to fully grasp what you are doing. Maybe you can use a default value for each parameter (for instance: `''`), and use that on my dataset query

Comment: I know your query works, I'm going to keep tweaking settings. Well thanks, I really appreciate your help @Lamak.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
WHERE (a = @A or @A IS NULL) AND (b=@b OR @b IS NULL)
```